# How can I parse this JSON Object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, rest

Looking for some guidance here on how can I extract Alok,Test and Test2

Object {value: "{"actors":["Alok","Test","Test2"]}"}

I have almost spent entire day to figure out the way to parse this JSON array but closest I reached is getting all characters printed in a single line.

My javascript implementation is:

```
        AJS.$.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            url: AJS.params.baseURL+"/rest/leangearsrestresource/1.0/message/list/{actor}",
            async: false,
            multiple: true
        }).done(function(result) {
                    AJS.log(result);
                    //var obj = JSON.parse(result);
                    //AJS.log(obj.actors[1]);

            //AJS.log("Actor is " + result.length);
            var output = '';
            for(var key in result) {
                AJS.log("Key: " + key + " value: " + result[key]);
                var myThing = result[key];
                var output = myThing.property
                AJS.log(output)
               // AJS.log(output.text)
                for( thingKey in myThing ) {

                    AJS.log(myThing[thingKey])
                }

            }
```

Also attaching the console screenshot[image]

Comment: Either use `dataType: 'json'` in the request or `result = JSON.parse( result );` in the callback. You currently just get a string and you should parse it before using it.

Comment: you need a JSON.parse(result), otherwise your 'result' is a string

Comment: If that is truly your JSON, the string is badly formed.

Answer (score 1):

The result object is not fully parsed it has a property value which contains a string so you have to parse the value of value property like this: JSON.parse(result.value) and you will get an object with one property "actors" whose value is an array with the strings "Alok","Test","Test2".

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a json data that, when parsed, results in a object with a key named "value" and its pair value that is another json string.

So you have to get that string and parse it again.

Then you can access it as a JavaScript object.

This is the `done` callback rewritten:

```
function( result ) {
    var json,
        obj,
        actors;

    json = result.value;
    obj = JSON.parse( json );
    actors = obj.actors;

    for( idx in actors ) {
        AJS.log( actors[ idx ] );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for( thingKey in myThing.actors ) {

    AJS.log(myThing[thingKey])
}
```

You need to modify your code. Because the index is `actors`. `actors` is a array. So you can iterate array in `for` loop.

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure that you have a valid JSON, use this:
jQuery.parseJSON(str)

Comment: [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering as the result object was not fully parsed.